# How to change values (that are lists) in python Data Frame based on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame *'songDataFrame'* with information about songs. There are three columns: *'artist', 'title', 'genres'*. The first two are string and *'genres'* contains lists of genres. It looks like this:

```
id  artist             title         genres
1   'Sarah Bareilles'  'Opening Up'  ['acoustic','pop', 'piano']
2   'Post Malone'      'Stay'        ['Hip-Hop', 'rap', 'trap']
3   'Dean Lewis'       'Waves'       ['alternative', 'guitar', 'indie']
4   'Billie Eilish'    'Watch'       ['indie', 'indie pop', 'pop']
5   'Passenger'        'Let Her Go'  ['metal', 'screamo', 'gore']
```

Genres for artist 'Passenger' are wrong. I want to change the existing list to ['indie rock', 'folk rock'].

If it wasn't a list, but I was replacing with a string I would just do:

```
mask = songDataFrame.artist =='Passenger'
songDataFrame.loc[mask, 'genres'] = 'indie folk'
```

This way it works fine. When instead of 'indie folk' I put ['indie rock', 'folk rock'],

```
mask = songDataFrame.artist =='Passenger'
songDataFrame.loc[mask, 'genres'] = ['indie folk','folk rock']
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Is there a way to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two-lines and use `loc` for assigning a string, make all column values string, then make them back to list:

```
import ast
songDataFrame.loc[songDataFrame['artist']=='Passenger','genres']="['indie folk','folk rock']"
songDataFrame['genres']=songDataFrame['genres'].astype(str).apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

And now:

```
print(songDataFrame)
```

Is:

```
   id           artist       title                        genres
0   1  Sarah Bareilles  Opening Up        [acoustic, pop, piano]
1   2      Post Malone        Stay          [Hip-Hop, rap, trap]
2   3       Dean Lewis       Waves  [alternative, guitar, indie]
3   4    Billie Eilish       Watch       [indie, indie pop, pop]
4   5        Passenger  Let Her Go       [indie folk, folk rock]
```

Comment: Worked like a dream! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without the extra package and the `literal_eval` trick:

```
mask = (songDataFrame.artist == 'Passenger').tolist().index(True)
songDataFrame.at[mask, 'genres'] = ['indie folk','folk rock']
```